# What does “would be gone for 4 months” mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this Tom Hanks interview ([Tom Hanks: On Acting](https://youtu.be/mXWQD8Tyve0)) at around [38 seconds](https://youtu.be/mXWQD8Tyve0?t=38) from the start:

> [How did you get started?]
>
> [...] It was just an offer to work in classical repertory theater in which the pay was going to be the professional experience that went along with it. And there was a group of us—we all went and we knew **we would be gone for 4 or 5 months**. We knew we would have something to do with either 5 or 6 productions that were in repertory. [...]

The phrase “will be gone for (a time period)” meaning someone will no longer be there for a period of time, that means Tom Hanks will leaves that group for 4 or 5 months. But the context is really strange to me, why does he suddenly say something like: “We went to a group, **but we would not be there for 4 month**, we would do some production at that group”.

That sentence is really out of context for me, what does he mean here?

Comment: I improved the context a bit. FYI, he says "we **would** be gone", not "we will be gone".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He means that everyone in the group will be "away from home" for four or five months.  He is talking about joining a repertory theatre company.  This is a group of actors who learn several plays and then tour different towns and theatres.  The group of people (presumably all people in his class at college) joined this tour, as assistants, stage-hands and so forth.

So Tom joined a group of people who were all gone *from home* for four or five months

The sentence uses "future in the past" The "would" is the past tense of "will".  Tom is talking about the past, so "I know that I will be gone" is reported as "I knew that I would be gone".

While he was on tour, he was given the chance to act professionally (which enabled him to gain enough experience to get roles in TV and later films)

Comment: Mention: [future in the past](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-in-the-past)